# Where does Xcode store its indexes?

Tags: xcode

Where does Xcode store the indexes for the "jump to definition" feature?

I'm interested in both Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Xcode 3 all this information seems to be stored in the directory `build/<project_name>.build/<project_name>.pbxindex`. You'll see a bunch of `.pbxtree` files there plus a further subdirectory `strings.pbxstrings`. It will probably take a while to reverse engineer the format of all this data, as it's not published anywhere AFAIK.